# PHP Server Sent Events infinite loop STOPS when client disconnects

Tags: php, iis, server-sent-events

So I've seen a few questions about SSE from people asking why when their client disconnects their while loop keeps running. I'm currently having the opposite issue where my while loop STOPS running on client disconnect.

I'm using sockets within the script to communicate with 3rd party equipment and this issue is stopping me from "cleaning up" the actions of the script when a client disconnects (ie, send the correct strings to the 3rd party device to say "goodbye" before closing the socket).

The Mozilla (and many other SSE guides) mention to include the following bit of code within the while loop to check if the client has disconnected, and use that to do any clean up work before exiting the script:

```
if (connection_aborted()){
  // Do cleanup work here
  exit();
}
```

But instead, the script is just terminating there and then on client disconnect without even going inside of this if statement.

I've tried ignore_user_abort(); set to TRUE and FALSE with neither having effect. There is also a flush() command just before the IF statement as I know connection_aborted() needs to have data sent to the client to know if the connection is still active, but with the script immediately terminating this is also not having any effect on the issue.
I've tried register_shutdown_function() and put my cleanup code in a function, but this also doesn't work.

PHP version is 7.0.9 running on Windows Server 2016 IIS 10. Could it be a Windows/IIS thing?

Comment: PHP 7.0 reached of life a long while ago, so even if you want to isolate the culprit you need to upgrade first to a supported PHP version by the community, https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: I suggest you check anything in the IIS logs/Event Viewer in Windows.

Comment: @LexLi I've updated to the latest V8.2.0 and the result is the same.

Comment: @YurongDai There is nothing showing in the IIS logs about this issue. The only issue showing relating to php is that the mysql module can't load due to the file not being available so i've turned this module off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I stumbled across a php bug report from 2011 highlighting this exact issue on IIS and it appears it is an issue with IIS and is by design.

[PHP Bug Report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60586#1378935714)

I've since switched platforms to Apache on windows and the issue no longer occurs. I've posted the above incase anyone else has a similar issue.